# Eclipse Markdown Plugin - How to open Markdown HTML Preview when double clicking a .md file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, markdown

I just installed the Markdown plugin for Eclipse. I'd like to have it so that if I double click a *.md* file, it will open the markdown HTML preview view, or at a minimum be able to right click and view in Markdown HTML Preview.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps this is not exactly what you've asked for, but if you open the *Markdown HTML Preview* view and leave it open, it will automatically change to whatever *.MD* file you are actually editing. So, just leave that *View* open and it will perform as you want. You can then save your *Perspective* to keep that preference (Eclipse does that for you anyway).

More, if you're working with [GitHub Flavoured Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) you'll want to check the [GitHub Flavored Markdown viewer plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/github-flavored-markdown-viewer-plugin), which actually works with the Markdown plugin, but does the rendering as you can see in GitHub. In this case, you'll actually have what you're looking for: if you right click any *.MD* file under your project explorer, there is an option to *Show in GFM View*, which will open that view in case it is not open already.

## Update (September 2020)

There is one [fork in Github](https://github.com/bitmc/gfm_viewer) that claims to be compatible with **Eclipse 2020-03**. I didn't test it myself, since I am not longer using Eclipse. Thanks to Daniel Armbrust who provided this link in the [marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/github-flavored-markdown-viewer-plugin) comments.

Comment: How to create a dependency between the HTML file generated and the .md file?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve. Anyway, I think you should open a new question.

Comment: It's not compatible with the latest version of Eclipse.

Comment: @AmgadHanafy Which version did you mean?

Comment: @Danijel 2019-06

Answer (score 3):

Open your `README.md` using the markdown editor (**Generate Markdown Preview** option) and open the markdown preview window: `Window` > `Show View` > `Markdown View`.

This will render your `.md` file.

Answer (score 1):

(not exact answer)

If you are keyboard/shortcuts fan you can press `CTRL+PgUp` right after you open the `*.md` file, which will switch to the preview screen.